# Convert string to complex valued numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string

```
s = "[0. -0.002j,-0.002-0.002j,-0.003+0.j ],\n[0.01+0.j , 0.001-0.001j,-0. +0.0009j]]"
```

And I'd like to convet this to `np.array`. Using `np.fromstring` `np.loadtxt` and using JSON as an intermediate step all have problems with complex numbers (and it's even worse with comma separation.

This type of output is generated by `np.array2string(x,separator=',')`.

What would be elegant/concise/canonical way of doing this conversion?

---

Initial missing bracket is a typo, keeping original statement of the question so that answers make more sense.

Comment: `np.array(eval('[' + s.replace('\n','')))`

Comment: about missing bracket - copying typo, thanks!

Comment: Generating the string with `repr(x.tolist())` would be safer.  Better yet a `pickle.dumps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fix the missing leading bracket, you can treat this as a regular list with [the `ast` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[[0. -0.002j,-0.002-0.002j,-0.003+0.j ],\n[0.01+0.j , 0.001-0.001j,-0. +0.0009j]]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[[-0.002j, (-0.002-0.002j), (-0.003+0j)], [(0.01+0j), (0.001-0.001j), 0.0009j]]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))
array([[ 0.   -0.002j , -0.002-0.002j , -0.003+0.j    ],
       [ 0.01 +0.j    ,  0.001-0.001j ,  0.   +0.0009j]])
```